# How did I get >100% world completion in Super Meatboy?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I just finished getting all of the bandages and A+ on every level in world 2 of Super Meatboy.  Somehow, this has resulted in me having a completion of 109%.  I figured "meh, probably some screwy thing about A+ on the glitch stage too".  So I made sure I have every bandage and A+ on every stage in world 1.  I do, but the % is only 100.

Is >100% achievable in every world?  If so, what's the general strategy for getting it?

Comment: Interestingly, I've got >100% on world 3 without even finishing all of the dark levels, let alone A+ them.  Guessing its a "feature" to keep the actual number in the dark. XD

Comment: I believe there was/is a bug allowing you to sometimes replay a level too quickly and get bandages multiple times which sometimes would still add to your percentages. It would up your counts on level completions as well. Not sure which version you are playing though and if that is the case.

Comment: 106% indicates you have completed 100% of levels + bandages, plus the 6 glitch zones

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple glitches with the completion percentages. You can find quite a few references to it if you do some searching a bit for "Super Meat Boy" and numbers like "109", "96", etc. [Here's an example topic on a forum](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/meatboy/show_msgs.php?topic_id=m-1-56978128&pid=990836).

You can mostly ignore the actual numbers it shows, just make sure you beat or A+-ed all the levels, and collected all the bandages. Hopefully it'll be fixed in a patch.